# Accessing Spark Web UI from another place than where the job actually ran

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have a spark cluster with 1 master 9nodes.I am running in standalone-mode. I do not have access to a web browser from any of the nodes in the cluster (I am connecting to the nodes through ssh --it is a grid5000 cluster).
I was wondering, is there any possibility to access Spark Web UI in this case? I tried by copying the logs from my cluster in SPARK_PATH/work on my local machine (leaving the impression that the jobs that ran in the cluster were ran on my local machine). This idea came after reading this part from the documentation:

***If an application has logged events over the course of its lifetime, then the Standalone master’s web UI will automatically re-render the application’s UI after the application has finished.***

But it did not work. What I can see in the UI is:

> Applications: 0 Running, 0 Completed 
>   Drivers: 0 Running, 0 Completed
>   Status: ALIVE

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to copy anything, just access port 8080 on the master machine or port 4040 on the application machine (while the application is running). If the machines are not externally accessible you have to tunnel through SSH.

Tunneling through SSH is a popular topic, just search for it. I personally use `ssh -D 9999` and then set up `localhost:9999` as a proxy using the FoxyProxy plugin which exists for both Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: What if I cannot ssh directly to the master? First, I have to ssh to a frontend and from that frontend to the master.Can I do ssh tunneling?

Comment: If you can SSH to a machine from which a browser could access the master, then that is enough. If the master's port 8080 is not accessible from the frontend machine, then you need another tunnel. It's not a problem at all. You `ssh -L9999:localhost:9999` to the first machine, then `ssh -D9999` to the second machine. Then you can set `localhost:9999` as a proxy in the browser.

Comment: So I have been trying to do that. In order to get to my master I first have to ssh to frontend1 and from frontend1 I have to ssh to frontend2 and from frontend2 I can ssh to master. So I am doing it like this: from my local PC: ssh -L 8080:localhost:8080 frontend1; from frontend1: ssh -L 8080:localhost:8080 frontend2;  and from frontend2 ssh -D 8080 master. I used FoxyProxy on my local machine and set localhost:8080 as a proxy. It doesn´t work..What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Wow, what a setup! It's hard to say what's wrong. Maybe it's my suggestion. I think there are good guides online for setting this up, or you can ask a system administrator there. (I mean someone must be administering this crazy configuration :).) Something you can try though is `ssh -L2222:frontend2:22 frontend1`, then `ssh -p 2222 localhost`. This should get you logged in to `frontend2`, tunneled through `frontend1`. If this works you can play around the same way until you reach `master`.